# Iterative depth-first search to find longest path in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, stack, iteration, depth-first-search, maze

I'm a fairly beginner/novice JavaScript coder, without much CS/math experience, trying to program part of a web-based game to check for the "longest road" across all possible paths, e.g. the longest road score in Catan.

I've tried to do this using a probably-wrong implementation of an iterative depth-first search using a stack. It's supposed to walk each possible path, then when it hits a dead end, check whether the current path is longer than the previous longest path, and overwrite if so.

My code doesn't quite work, though; it doesn't seem to actually walk/check all possible paths when hitting intersections or other variations.

I have done all kinds of research into DFS and these kinds of algorithms and have had an extremely rough time trying to get my head around it; this is the closest I've come to something that works. I'm sure the code could be made more elegant via recursion or somesuch, but at this point I just want to understand why what I've written here isn't functional.

Relevant code below. I'm sure it's a mess in many different ways, but hopefully at least the function names and such are clear enough that this is enough context to figure out what's ultimately going wrong:

```
function walkAllPaths(node, network, t) {
    var stack = [ node ];
    var path = new Array();
    var visited = new Array();

    while (stack.length) {
        var curr = stack.pop();
        visited.push(curr);

        var moveNorth = myNeighbor(curr, "north");
        var moveSouth = myNeighbor(curr, "south");
        var moveWest = myNeighbor(curr, "west");
        var moveEast = myNeighbor(curr, "east");

        if (isValidMove(network, visited, t, moveNorth)) { stack.push(moveNorth); }
        else if (isValidMove(network, visited, t, moveWest)) { stack.push(moveWest); }
        else if (isValidMove(network, visited, t, moveSouth)) { stack.push(moveSouth); }
        else if (isValidMove(network, visited, t, moveEast)) { stack.push(moveEast); }

        else {
            if (visited.length > path.length) {
                path.length = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < visited.length; i++) {
                    path.push(visited[i]);
                }
            }
            visited.pop();
        }
        console.log(visited);
    }

    return path;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried coloring the paths that have been traversed? That could help you narrow down the problem where it's happening.

Comment: Check http://www.primaryobjects.com/maze/ and http://www.primaryobjects.com/maze/scripts/tremauxAlgorithm.js

Comment: @EhsanMahmud - I've been using the console.log command in there to look at all the paths being formed as the function iterates. it catches some routes perfectly, but then seems to ignore or never even check others. it's perfect on linear routes, but isn't properly running back through to junctions/intersections.

Comment: Can you give an example input and output? Would be easier to debug.

Comment: Any particular reason you're writing an iterative DFS rather than doing it recursively, which is much easier to implement?

Comment: Only that, though I'm sure it is easier to implement, I was having a really hard time getting my head around the logic of the recursive version. As I mentioned, not much experience in this arena :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to figure out what was going on! I am still fairly positive that this is not at all an optimal solution, but it now does exactly what it's supposed to -- walk all valid paths and then return an array containing the longest path it walked. Here's the final code:

```
function walkAllPaths(node, network, t) {
    var stack = [ node ];
    var path = [];
    var visited = [];
    var longPath = [];

    while (stack.length) {
        var curr = stack.pop();

        visited.push(curr);
        if (curr !== path[path.length - 1]) { path.push(curr); }

        var moveNorth = myNeighbor(curr, "north");
        var moveSouth = myNeighbor(curr, "south");
        var moveWest = myNeighbor(curr, "west");
        var moveEast = myNeighbor(curr, "east");

        if (isValidMove(network, visited, t, moveNorth)) { stack.push(moveNorth); }
        else if (isValidMove(network, visited, t, moveWest)) { stack.push(moveWest); }
        else if (isValidMove(network, visited, t, moveSouth)) { stack.push(moveSouth); }
        else if (isValidMove(network, visited, t, moveEast)) { stack.push(moveEast); }
        else {
            if (path.length > longPath.length) {
                longPath.length = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
                    longPath.push(path[i]);
                }
            }
            path.pop();
            if (path.length) { stack.push(path[path.length - 1]); }
        }
    }

    return longPath;
}
```

Thanks to those who offered thoughts/suggestions!